# Replacing Strings in Google Sheets from Dropdown List

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, replace, dropdown, google-sheets-formula

How can I replace strings in Google Sheets in another cell depending on the selection in a dropdown list? I have a dropdown list with let's say *apple, banana* and I want to replace the word with another word depending on the selection in the dropdown list. Let's say if I choose *apple* in the list I want to replace the string with *stone*, if it's *banana* I want to replace it with *car*. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

the technique is called "nesting of formulae":

```
=IF(A1="apple", "stone", 
 IF(A1="banana", "car", ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks good idea but I found a even simplier way after trying around for a bit.
    SWITCH(A1; 0; "x"; 1; "y")